# PHP Slim Obtener parametros POST

Tags: php, slim

Necesito obtener los parametros post con slim framework php, esta es mi ruta post:

```
$app->post('/agregar', function ($req, $res) {
  //obtiene e bodyParsed    
  $data = $req->getParsedBody();
    //aca se puede aplicar un forEach para sacar todas las variable
   //POST pero necesito solo una variable 



});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $req->getParsedBody()['text'];
```

Usé esto y funcionó.